# Clang AST Matcher's "AND" and "OR"

Tags: clang, clang-ast-matchers

Is it possible to use `or` in function declarations? like:

```
functionDecl(hasName("a") or hasName("b"))
```

or we have to use `addMatcher` to add more matchers to get the same result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several narrowing matchers that form logical combinations of other matchers: `anyOf` is like "or", `allOf` can implement "and", and `unless` is like "not". Your example might look like

```
functionDecl(
  anyOf(
    hasName("a"),
    hasName("b") ))
```